# How to ddply() without sorting?

Tags: r, sorting, plyr

I use the following code to summarize my data, grouped by Compound, Replicate and Mass.

```
summaryDataFrame <- ddply(reviewDataFrame, .(Compound, Replicate, Mass), 
  .fun = calculate_T60_Over_T0_Ratio)
```

An unfortunate side effect is that the resulting data frame is sorted by those fields. I would like to do this and keep Compound, Replicate and Mass in the same order as in the original data frame. Any ideas? I tried adding a "Sorting" column of sequential integers to the original data, but of course I can't include that in the .variables since I don't want to 'group by' that, and so it is not returned in the summaryDataFrame.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `write.table`; title should be changed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This came up on the `plyr` mailing list a while back (raised by @kohske no less) and this is a solution offered by Peter Meilstrup for limited cases:

```
#Peter's version used a function gensym to
# create the col name, but I couldn't track down
# what package it was in.
keeping.order <- function(data, fn, ...) { 
  col <- ".sortColumn"
  data[,col] <- 1:nrow(data) 
  out <- fn(data, ...) 
  if (!col %in% colnames(out)) stop("Ordering column not preserved by function") 
  out <- out[order(out[,col]),] 
  out[,col] <- NULL 
  out 
} 

#Some sample data 
d <- structure(list(g = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), v = c(-1.90127112738315, 
-1.20862680183042, -1.13913266070505, 0.14899803094742, -0.69427656843677, 
0.872558638137971)), .Names = c("g", "v"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame") 

#This one resorts
ddply(d, .(g), mutate, v=scale(v)) #does not preserve order of d 

#This one does not
keeping.order(d, ddply, .(g), mutate, v=scale(v)) #preserves order of d
```

Please do read the [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/manipulatr/browse_thread/thread/72557932fec178ee/c222306a332a714f?lnk=gst&q=ddply+preserve#c222306a332a714f) for Hadley's notes about why this functionality may not be general enough to roll into `ddply`, particularly as it probably applies in your case as you are likely returning fewer rows with each piece.

*Edited to include a strategy for more general cases*

If `ddply` is outputting something that is sorted in an order you do not like you basically have two options: specify the desired ordering on the splitting variables beforehand using ordered factors, or manually sort the output after the fact.

For instance, consider the following data:

```
d <- data.frame(x1 = rep(letters[1:3],each = 5), 
                x2 = rep(letters[4:6],5),
                x3 = 1:15,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

using strings, for now. `ddply` will sort the output, which in this case will entail the default lexical ordering:

```
> ddply(d,.(x1,x2),summarise, val = sum(x3))
  x1 x2 val
1  a  d   5
2  a  e   7
3  a  f   3
4  b  d  17
5  b  e   8
6  b  f  15
7  c  d  13
8  c  e  25
9  c  f  27


> ddply(d[sample(1:15,15),],.(x1,x2),summarise, val = sum(x3))
  x1 x2 val
1  a  d   5
2  a  e   7
3  a  f   3
4  b  d  17
5  b  e   8
6  b  f  15
7  c  d  13
8  c  e  25
9  c  f  27
```

If the resulting data frame isn't ending up in the "right" order, it's probably because you really want some of those variables to be ordered factors. Suppose that we really wanted `x1` and `x2` ordered like so:

```
d$x1 <- factor(d$x1, levels = c('b','a','c'),ordered = TRUE)
d$x2 <- factor(d$x2, levels = c('d','f','e'), ordered = TRUE)
```

Now when we use `ddply`, the resulting sort will be as we intend:

```
> ddply(d,.(x1,x2),summarise, val = sum(x3))
  x1 x2 val
1  b  d  17
2  b  f  15
3  b  e   8
4  a  d   5
5  a  f   3
6  a  e   7
7  c  d  13
8  c  f  27
9  c  e  25
```

The moral of the story here is that if `ddply` is outputting something in an order you didn't intend, it's a good sign that you should be using ordered factors for the variables you're splitting on.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be working for me "almost". How do I keep the `.sortColumn` in the returned data of my function?
`calculate_T60_Over_T0_Ratio <- function(df) {`

    `## checks to make sure the right time points are being used for the ratio`

    `t60Value = df[which(df[,"Time"] == "t=60"),"Result"]`

    `t0Value = df[which(df[,"Time"] == "t=0"),"Result"]`

    `if (t0Value == 0){`

      `print("Error -- Divide by zero!")`

      `return ("NA")`

    `} else {`

    `return (t60Value / t0Value) `

    `}`

`}`

Comment: @James If you want to keep the `.sortColumn` in the results, you could probably just omit the line `out[,col] <- NULL` from `keeping.order`.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I am getting the error from `keeping.order` because the `.sortColumn` is not being returned by my function (see above).

Comment: @James - Sorry, I misunderstood. Remember that I noted in my answer that this strategy won't work if your function is returning fewer rows, which it appears you are. Something similar is likely possible, but it will have to be specifically tailored to your data and function, so I (or anyone else) can't help unless you edit your question to include some sample data. But I can tell you now it will simply entail calling `ddply` and then just re-sorting your data afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually ended up adding an 'indexing' column to the original data frame. It consisted of two columns `pasted` with `sep="_"`. Then I made another data frame made of only `unique` members of the 'indexing' column and a counter `1:length(df)`. I did my `ddply()` on the data which returned a sorted data frame. Then to get things back in the original order I did `merge()` the results data frame and the index data frame (making sure the columns are named the same thing makes this easier). Finally, I did `order` and removed the extraneous columns.

Not an elegant solution, but one that works.

Thanks for the assist. It got me thinking in the right direction.