# Maintaining order in split-apply-combine problems

Tags: r, plyr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to ddply() without sorting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235421/how-to-ddply-without-sorting)

I have the following data frame

```
dd1 = data.frame(cond = c("D","A","C","B","A","B","D","C"), val = c(11,7,9,4,3,0,5,2))
dd1
  cond val
1    D  11
2    A   7
3    C   9
4    B   4
5    A   3
6    B   0
7    D   5
8    C   2
```

and now need to compute cumulative sums respecting the factor level in cond. The results should look like that:

```
> dd2 = data.frame(cond = c("D","A","C","B","A","B","D","C"), val = c(11,7,9,4,3,0,5,2), cumsum=c(11,7,9,4,10,4,16,11))
> dd2
  cond val cumsum
1    D  11     11
2    A   7      7
3    C   9      9
4    B   4      4
5    A   3     10
6    B   0      4
7    D   5     16
8    C   2     11
```

It is important to receive the result data frame in the same order as the input data frame because there are other variables bound to that.

I tried `ddply(dd1, .(cond), summarize, cumsum = cumsum(val))` but it didn't produce the result I expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ave` instead.

```
dd1$cumsum <- ave(dd1$val, dd1$cond, FUN=cumsum)
```

Comment: +1 `ave` is a great tool for this particular problem, and one that is often overlooked.

Answer (score 3):

If doing this by hand is an option then `split()` and `unsplit()` with a suitable `lapply()` inbetween will do this for you.

```
dds <- split(dd1, dd1$cond)
dds <- lapply(dds, function(x) transform(x, cumsum = cumsum(x$val)))
unsplit(dds, dd1$cond)
```

The last line gives

```
> unsplit(dds, dd1$cond)
  cond val cumsum
1    D  11     11
2    A   7      7
3    C   9      9
4    B   4      4
5    A   3     10
6    B   0      4
7    D   5     16
8    C   2     11
```

I separated the three steps, but these could be strung together or placed in a function if you are doing a lot of this.

Comment: Placed in a function... like `ave`? :P

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I always forget that one!

Comment: It's a very useful function that's hindered by its poor name choice. +1 for reinventing the wheel, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

A `data.table` solution:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.frame(dd1)
dt[, c.val := cumsum(val),by=cond]
> dt
#    cond val c.val
# 1:    D  11    11
# 2:    A   7     7
# 3:    C   9     9
# 4:    B   4     4
# 5:    A   3    10
# 6:    B   0     4
# 7:    D   5    16
# 8:    C   2    11
```